# Bash how to sort a list of files named filedaymonthyear.mp4

Tags: bash, list, file, sorting

I have a list of files :

```
file01022020.mp4
file03022020.mp4
file12032020.mp4
file22032020.mp4
...
```

I need to sort them in the date order, how can I do that?
Because if I use something like :

```
ls *.mp4 > mylist.txt
```

I don't have the right order.

Comment: if possible, it is simpler to name the files year-month-day: you get the sorting for free

Comment: Try piping to `sort`

Comment: Or use use `ls` with `-t` option

Comment: the problem with `sort` is you don't have any character in file name that can be used as column delimiter (maybe fixed wide can be used instead)? if you really want to sort based on file name you can do that in two steps with index file (or as others said rename into different pattern) **edit:** seems the sort `-M` flag does what you need

Comment: `sort` can defined keys by offset, if the names are all literally "file"something...

Answer (score 4):

Sort can define keydef by offsets.

```
printf "%s\n" *.mp4 |  sort -k1.9,1.12 -k1.7,1.8 -k1.5,1.6 
file01022020.mp4
file03022020.mp4
file12032020.mp4
file22032020.mp4
```

In this example, the entire line is considered to be "field 1".
The starting string `file` occupies offsets 0-3.
offsets 4-5 are the Day.
offsets 6-7 are the Month.
offsets 8-11 are the Year.

This defines the keys in priority order, so sorts by year, then month, then day.

No need to spawn a bunch of processes or fight with regexes unless you enjoy that.  (I kinda do, lol)

Comment: This will work fine, as far as every filename has the same number of characters.

Comment: I think the key field uses 1 based indices, so the correct answer is printf "%s\n" *.mp4 |  sort -k1.9,1.12 -k1.7,1.8 -k1.5,1.6. If you add file01102020.mp4 to your sample it will end in first position instead of last were it belongs in this set.

Comment: let me also add: you dont need printf "%s\n" *.mp4. You can use "ls -1 |sort ..."

Comment: I switched it from `ls` to `printf` because, as a habit, I don't parse `ls`, and I always try to use built-ins that spawn fewer processes. In this case, it doesn't matter. 

Tried the offsets both ways, never set them back after debugging something unrelated and stupid that I was doing. I set them back, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are not too far away from a solution. The trick is

1. to invert the day/month/year group
2. then sort alphabetically
3. to invert the group again in order to reconstruct the actual file names

```
    ls *.mp4 > mylist.txt
    cat mylist.txt | sed -E 's#file(..)(..)(....)#file\3\2\1#' | sort | sed -E 's#file(....)(..)(..)#file\3\2\1#' > sorted.txt
```

Comment: It's kinda like a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) XD

Answer (score 2):

Using the decorate/sort/undecorate idiom:

```
printf "%s\n" *.mp4                         |
sed -E 's/.*(..)(..)(....)\.mp4$/\3\2\1 &/' |
sort                                        |
sed 's/[^ ]* //'
```

With the assumptions that the `.mp4` extension is always preceded by a date in `DDMMYYYY` format and no filename contains a newline character.

Comment: MORE like a Schwartzian Transform. ;)

Comment: @PaulHodges I didn't know the `decorate/sort/undecorate` idiom is also called Schwartzian Transform.

Comment: It's a Perl thing. c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 | sort -k1.9,1.12 -k1.7,1.8 -k1.5,1.6
```

naming your files fileYYYYMMDD.mp4

```
ls -1
```

is enough (as correctly noted ls already sorts)

Comment: `ls` already sorts, so the `|sort` in `ls -1|sort` is not necessary. And also, parsing the output of `ls` shouldn't be recommended, although it won't make any difference for this case probably.

Comment: Thank you @user1708042 , i used your suggestion, it worked like a charm.